# Why is my integration test complaining about missing RestTemplate wiring in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-test, spring-rest, spring-resttemplate

Why is my integration test complaining about missing `RestTemplate` wiring in `Spring Boot` ?

What can I do to fix this integration test?

Moreover, is this an integration test or a unit test? Based on my understanding this test is making a call to a mock server which is an external entity (outside of the class-under-test) hence it is an integration test. Is my understanding correct ?

**pom.xml**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

**src/main/java/RestTemplateConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfig {
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
        Collection<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> clientHttpRequestInterceptors = List.of(new RestTemplateInterceptor());
        return new RestTemplateBuilder()
                .errorHandler(new CustomClientErrorHandler())
                .interceptors(clientHttpRequestInterceptors)
                .build();
    }
}
```

**src/main/java/AccountService.java**

```
@Service
@Log4j2
public class AccountService {

    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public Account getAccount() throws Exception {
        //build uri
        URI uri = new URI(http://api.demo.com/api/account)
        log.info("uri: " + uri);

        //hit api
        ResponseEntity<Account> result = this.restTemplate.getForEntity(uri, Account.class);
        log.info("result: " + result);

        //parse result
        Account account = null;
        if (result.getStatusCodeValue() == 200) {
            account = result.getBody();
        }
        log.info("account: " + account);
        return account;
    }

}
```

**src/test/java/AccountServiceIntegrationTest.java**

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@RestClientTest(AccountService.class)
public class AccountServiceIntegrationTest {

    @Autowired
    private AccountService instance;
    @Autowired
    private MockRestServiceServer server;
    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        Account account = new Account();
        account.setCanTrade(true);
        String accountJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(account);
        this.server.expect(requestTo("/api/v3/account"))
                .andRespond(withSuccess(accountJson, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetAccount() throws Exception {
        Account account = this.instance.getAccount();
        assertThat(account.isCanTrade()).isEqualTo(true);
    }

}
```

**Error Log:**

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field restTemplate in com.demo.service.AccountService required a bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

The following candidates were found but could not be injected:
    - Bean method 'restTemplate' in 'WebClientRestTemplateAutoConfiguration' not loaded because @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.test.webclient.register-rest-template) found different value in property 'register-rest-template'


Action:

Consider revisiting the entries above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' in your configuration.

2020-05-16 17:01:32.874 ERROR 13080 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@ca30bc1] to prepare test instance [com.demo.service.AccountServiceIntegrationTest@50d13246]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123) ~[spring-test-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118) ~[spring-test-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:43) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244) ~[spring-test-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:98) ~[spring-test-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:337) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:342) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:337) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:336) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:259) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:252) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:251) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:29) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:106) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.5.2.jar:5.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:107) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:107) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:75) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.5.2.jar:1.5.2]
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69) ~[junit5-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accountService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'restTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:130) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:882) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:126) ~[spring-boot-test-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 64 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1700) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1256) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1210) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640) ~[spring-beans-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
    ... 82 common frames omitted

Class transformation time: 0.0298959s for 4189 classes or 7.136762950584865E-6s per class

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I understand that I'm quite late, but maybe this can be useful for some people who will encounter the same problem.

The reason Spring doesn't see your `RestTemplate` is because `RestClientTest` is very limited in what it configures. It literally disables all regular auto configuration mechanisms and leaves you with your `@SpringBootApplication` class, a class you specified in `@RestTemplate`, `RestTemplateBuilder` and `MockRestServiceServer`.

If you want to add `RestTemplate` you have several options:

- Put it into your `@SpringBootApplication` class;
- Annotate your test with `@ImportAutoConfiguration(classes = RestTemplateConfig.class)`, which will explicitly tell Spring to load it;
- Annotate your test with `@AutoConfigureWebClient(registerRestTemplate = true)`, which will make the property `spring.test.webclient.register-rest-template` true and will allow `RestClientTest` auto configuration to create `RestTemplate`.

What is funny here is that I followed the error message and made `spring.test.webclient.register-rest-template` true in my properties file, but that didn't work. After some time I discovered that `@AutoConfigureWebClient` simply overrides anything I have in properties.

P.S. You had a unit test, since you weren't talking to a real server, but a mocked one.

Comment: Special thanks for pointing out "@AutoConfigureWebClient(...)" :)

Comment: A minor correction -- instead of RestTemplateConfig.class, it should be RestTemplateAutoConfiguration.class
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/client/RestTemplateAutoConfiguration.html